# How to correct "With a growing tech sector in Vancouver and a highly transferable skill set, Maisie can easily find a job"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice, attachment-ambiguity, dangling-modifier

> With *a growing tech sector in Vancouver* and *a highly transferable skill set*, Maisie can reasonably expect to find a suitable job in her field. [The lady is a computer programmer: this is discussed prior to the sentence]

I am wondering if the dependent clause is idiomatically correct. I wrote the sentence, but now I have doubts. So the lady has a skill set, but she does not have the "tech sector in Vancouver".

Let's say

*a growing tech sector in Vancouver* (noun phrase) = *this*

*a highly transferable skill set* (noun phrase) = *that*

My mindset was to convey "With ***this*** and ***that***, Maisie can reasonably expect ..."

However, I have been told (by excellent native speakers) that the two things (*this* and *that*) are different. But I don't know how to correct this.

Note that individually these are correct:

> With *a growing tech sector in Vancouver*, Maisie can reasonably expect ...
>
> With *a highly transferable skill set*, Maisie can reasonably expect ...

Together, however, they are wrong.

P.S: What is this issue/problem called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advice you were given was wrong—it definitely is of the same construction as *with this and that*. So too would be *with one thing and another*, or any other construction that replaces the noun phrases with pronouns.

For additional clarity, however, you could tweak the sentence slightly:

> With ***there being*** a growing tech sector in Vancouver and ***her having*** a highly transferable skill set, Maisie can easily find a job.

This avoids the possible misinterpretation in the original of Maisie having *a growing tech sector*.

Comment: Jason, while I am incorporating your suggested changes, I am wondering if the my original sentence bothered you. Like, was the original horrible?

Comment: @AIQ No, it certainly wasn't horrible. I wouldn't have rushed to correct anything normally; I only did so because it was questioned.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the original sentence to be passive voice, since the thing we are actually talking about is Maisie and her job prospects. As a reasonably educated, native American English speaker, I don't have too big of a problem understanding the sentence as written. It makes sense and does not feel like it was written by a non-native speaker. Perhaps it could be improved by turning it around such as:

> Maisie can reasonably expect to find a suitable job in her field because she has a highly transferable skill set and there is a growing tech sector in Vancouver.

This version clarifies Maisie has the skill set and the growing tech sector is a property of Vancouver.

If you were passionate about keeping the original phrasing perhaps something like this would also achieve that clarity:

> Because there is a growing tech sector in Vancouver and the fact she has a highly transferable skill set, Maisie can reasonably expect to find a suitable job in her field.

Comment: How do you analyse the sentence as being in the passive voice?